# Spark ML Library

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am testing this Scala code that I found in the MLlib: Main Guide
[Machine Learning Library (MLlib) Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html)

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Matrix, Vectors, Vector}
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import scala.collection.Seq

object BasicStatistics {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val data: Seq[Vector] = Seq(
      Vectors.sparse(4, Seq((0, 1.0), (3, -2.0))),
      Vectors.dense(4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 3.0),
      Vectors.dense(6.0, 7.0, 0.0, 8.0),
      Vectors.sparse(4, Seq((0, 9.0), (3, 1.0))))

    val df = data.map(Tuple1.apply).toDF("features")
    val Row(coeff1: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(df, "features").head
    println(s"Pearson correlation matrix:\n $coeff1")

    val Row(coeff2: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(df, "features", "spearman").head
    println(s"Spearman correlation matrix:\n $coeff2")

  }
}
```

But this line is reporting an error.

```
val df = data.map(Tuple1.apply).toDF("features")
```

It says,
    "value toDF is not a member of Seq[(org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector,)]"

Seems like the value data (Seq[Vector]) does not have a map method?

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Below is from my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: The error is not about the map method... It says toDF doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of missing implicit conversion for `scala.Seq`.

To fix your problem add theses line

```
val name = "application name"
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName(name)
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: you're welcome @DaleAngus. Please make my answer as the correct one !

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you don't have a `SparkSession` or anything started. I believe `toDF` comes from importing `spark.implicits._` where `spark` is a `SparkSession`. The documentation sometimes does not make this clear and/or assumes you're working in the Spark shell, which creates the session automatically.

Your code does run in the spark shell.